# Search large harddrive efficiently for filetype with indexing

Tags: python, search, indexing

My question is somewhat related to "[How to improve searching with os.walk and fnmatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660284/how-to-improve-searching-with-os-walk-and-fnmatch-in-python-2-7-2)" but I want to expand a little.

Let's assume we have a file collection on a harddrive, which is about 10-50 TB big. I want to find all files with a specific ending on a regular basis. The collection changes daily as new files are added. In a first run, I want to store the attained information, so that in the following runs only the changed files have to be searched which I understand as some kind of indexing of the file system and hope to greatly speed up every consecutive search.

I prefer working in python, but a hint to a readymade software-solutions as well as open-source projects in other languages is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The most efficient way I can think of to do this is to do a once over index of the file system, then use real-time filesystem notifications like [pyinotify](https://github.com/seb-m/pyinotify)

Comment: That looks pretty promising as soon as the harddrive is accessed via Linux. Is there a similar solution for windows?

Comment: Sadly no; not that I'm aware of. Although I'm no *Windows* developer; there could be some [``win32``](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/) API(s) that *might* do something similar; but usually inotify-like API(s) are simulated with threading on Windows :/