# Python: get pathname of files using regex pattern recursively

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, filepath

If one want to get the (absolute) file paths (file listings) of all files with names of certain pattern how can this be done in Python (v 3.5 on unix). Something similar to the bash command `find -regex 'pattern'`. I have been looking as the [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#file-descriptor-operations), [glob](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/glob.html), [os.path](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#module-os.path)  and this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10660284/how-to-improve-searching-with-os-walk-and-fnmatch) but cannot get it together.

Say you want absolute paths to the files that  matches /.*[pat.txt]$/ and you have the below diretories:

```
/home/me/dir1/dir1a/filepat.txt #1
/home/me/dir1/dir1a/file.txt
/home/me/dir1/dir1a/filepat.png
/home/me/dir2/filepat.txt #2
/home/me/dir3/dir3a/dir3ab/filepat
/home/me/dir3/dir3a/dir3ac/filepat.txt #3 
/home/me/dir3/dir3a/dir3ac/filepat.png
```

Then you would get want the three indicated paths:

```
/home/me/dir1/dir1a/filepat.txt
/home/me/dir2/filepat.txt
/home/me/dir3/dir3a/dir3ac/filepat.txt
```

One try was:

```
import fnmatch
import os 
start_path = "/home/me/" 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_path):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, ".*pat.txt"):
        print(os.path.join(start_path, filename))
```

Comment: Python is misspelled in the post title  :-)

Comment: Embarrassing - but good catch

Comment: don't worry, I was in "debug mode"   ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `basename` and `in` operator

```
x = given list
>>> [i for i in x if 'pat.txt' in os.path.basename(i)]
['/home/me/dir1/dir1a/filepat.txt',
 '/home/me/dir2/filepat.txt',
 '/home/me/dir3/dir3a/dir3ac/filepat.txt']
```

Comment: Oh I completely missed `basename`

Comment: However, this solution will also fetch files like `filepat.txt.bak`

Comment: To fix that, just use `i.endswith('pat.txt')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew , we can still achieve this using `endswith('pat.txt')` if required :)

Comment: - Yes, but then it would fail to fetch `FILEPAT.TXT`. - We may use `lower()`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one using regexes, but for the simple case I would go with akash`s answer using `in` operator

```
import re
pattern = re.compile(r'.*pat\.txt$')

import fnmatch
import os 
start_path = "/home/me/" 
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(start_path):
    for filename in files:
        if pattern.find(filename):
            print(os.path.join(start_path, filename))
```

Comment: I was close I see. I think yours is very general though (+1)